# Old Apple ID's don't work

Tags: apple-id, music

I have 3 old Apple ID's that I used to purchase music. After upgrading to a new phone there are many songs I can't play because they are from the old ID's. Apple doesn't recognize them any more. How can I retrieve my music and authorize my latest phone to download the songs?

Answer (score 1):

When you say they "don't work" where exactly is this happening? Have you tried logging in directly via the apple website? Eg, (I forget the precise url, but) if you try http://cloud.me are you able to login with your old credentials there?

Have you tried via alternative mediums: iTunes directly (ie not via the phone)

And are you sure it's not an authorisation issue in that you have too many authorised computers/devices

Finally what happens if you try "forgotten password" on the website, does it say the old accounts are invalid?

Comment: I just thought I would add, when I first signed up with Apple, a VERY long time ago, I had inadvertently created two apple IDs with minor differences. I just tried the other one and it still (surprisingly) worked! I never downloaded music through it, but I had downloaded PAID apps :(